# Ruby tutorial for how to write stored procedures for PostgreSQL?

Tags: ruby, postgresql

I have heard that one in PostgreSQL can write stored procedures in Ruby.

But I haven't been able to find more information about it teaching one how to actually do it.

Could someone recommend good sources for that.

Thanks

Comment: Sadly, it appears that the PL/Ruby project is no longer being maintained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this website: http://moulon.inra.fr/ruby/plruby.html , it has some nice examples.

Comment: The site referenced above appears to have gone dark.

Answer (score 7):

Obviously, you need to install PL/Ruby. After that, you can write:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ruby_max(int4, int4) RETURNS int4 AS '
    if args[0].to_i > args[1].to_i
        return args[0]
    else
        return args[1]
    end
' LANGUAGE 'plruby';
```

Check its [GitHub repository](http://github.com/knu/postgresql-plruby) for installation instructions.

Comment: Some information regarding installation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/617600/installing-pl-ruby-for-postgresql